# Telerik Reports: How to group by the Date of a DateTime?

Tags: .net, telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

I need a report in which a set of events will be listed, and I need these events to be grouped by the Date component of the event DateTime.

When I create a group, I can determine the expression by which the records will be grouped, but I can't find a function that retrieves the Date of a DateTime. So I guess I need not to use these expressions and determine how to group programatically, but I have no idea of how to do this.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at custom expression extensions [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/expressions-extending-expressions.html). This will allow you to write your own expressions in CLR (C#/VB) and then use them as you would the built in Telerik expressions.